# A question on divisibility 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If, [in my past question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264649/264), $(2^{2m+1}-1)(2^{4m+2}+1)\mid
(2^{2n+1}-1)(2^{4n+2}+1)$, then what is the relationship between $m$
and $n$?

Comment: If $m=0$, $n$ arbitrary, the statement holds (left side is 5).

Answer (score 1):

If $2m+1\ |\ 2n+1$ then your divisibility statement will hold, since for $a$ and $b$ any odd natural numbers, $2^a-1 \ | 2^{ab}-1$ and also $4^a+1 \ | 4^{ab}+1.$ That is, if we write
$$f(m)=(2^{2m+1}-1)(2^{4m+2}+1)=(2^{2m+1}-1)(4^{2m+1}+1)$$ and $2m+1\ |\ 2n+1$ , we will have $f(m)\ | f(n),$ for example $f(1)\ | f(4)$ follows from $2\cdot 1+1=3$ being a divisor of $2 \cdot 4+1=9$, and in fact $f(4)/f(1)=294409.$